# With ASP.NET using ADO.NET any compelling reason to move from Oracle 10g to 11g

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net, oracle10g, oracle11g

I'm building a new .NET 4.0 ASP.NET MVC3 application and currently the database is on 9i, I requested moving to 10 or 11 and the Oracle DBA's have 10g and 11g , but prefer to use 10g.  They wanted to know if there are any good reasons that I would want/need/gain by using 11g with .NET    calling Stored Procedures with ADO.NET is how this application will work.
I don't plan on doing any cutting edge Oracle PL/SQL but I wanted to here back from .NET / Oracle developers that are at companies using 9i / 10g / 11g  and hear what the pros of using 10g vs 11g and if there are ANY cons to using 11g etc...

Comment: Who are *they*? The men in black?

Comment: @Darin  haha,  funny guy.  "They" are the DBA's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11g is the "current version" of Oracle (duh) *if you are going to upgrade anyway*, you should upgrade 'all the way'.

- Inevitably you will upgrade to
  version 12/13/42; the further you go now, the longer your shelf life.
- For a [full feature list look here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle11g/oracle_11g_new_features.htm). Pick the ones that apply to you.

Comment: But with .NET , what do I truly gain?  Any proven benchmarks on load and performance testing?

Comment: Oracle doesn't know about our care about .NET, nor should it. Your DBAs are trying to stay in their _comfort zone_. Is 11g going to make your .Net application better all by itself, not noticeably (see @Olafs answer & comment). Will it give you a lot of new features, see the feature list I already linked you to, but if you don't **use** those features, they don't matter. Is it still the still the right move, YES. The point is _you MUST upgrade, right_, the question to ask is not "Why go to 11g?" but rather, `"Why would you NOT go to 11g?"`. Because your DBAs don't want to do something new?

Comment: Thanks Cos.  IMO, DBA's and Admins are lazy  :(

Answer (score 3):

Oracle compels to move to the current version of their database by jacking up annual licensing fees for older versions starting July 1st. If you are licensing Oracle for a more or less serious server or use some advanced features, this is compelling enough.

Comment: As a .NET developer I want to know performance and load testing. If I can't state those to the CIO and DBA's then they are sticking me with 10g and NOT 11g  .  How about Beta EF with 10g vs 11g  any thoughts?

Comment: @Tom Stickel: We went through the Oracle 10g to 11gR2 upgrade throughout all our product lines in last 12 - 6 months. We are using Java stack, not .NET but I don't believe there would be material difference. Overall we got somewhat better performance on majority of servers except some old ones that were severely RAM-constrained. The biggest improvement was collecting stats. We had to write and tune our own stats process when migrating from 9i to 10g and now we were able to dump it and rely on the default Oracle stats settings.